# What is the best aproach to feed data to a custom UITableViewCell that has multiple labels - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with a custom viewCell which has three labels, `displayCarName`, `displayMpg` and `displayCarPrice`. I'm using three different arrays to feed each label in the tableView, everything is working fine but I feel like there is a better way to do this, may be using a single dictionary instead or something like that.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
    private var carNameList = [String]()
    private var mpgList = [Int]()
    private var carPriceList = [Double]()


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return carNameList.count
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.displayCarName!.text= carNameList[indexPath.row]
        cell.displayMpg!.text = String(mpgList[indexPath.row])
        cell.displayCarPrice!.text = String(carPriceList[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
```

Is this a common way to feed multiple labels in a table row? If not, can someone help me improve the code shown above?

FYI- I actually have more than three labels in each row but for simplicity I'm only showing three.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using is sometimes referred to as *parallel arrays*. This approach was commonplace in languages lacking support for structures.

Since Swift does have support for structures, a better approach would be to define a class representing a `Car`, with three properties for car's `Name`, `Mpg`, and `Price`, and then using a single list of `[Car]` in place of three separate lists:

```
class Car {
    let Name : String
    let Mpg : Int
    let Price : Double
    init(name: String, mpg : Int, price : Double ) {
        Name = name
        Mpg = mpg
        Price = price
    }
}
...
private var carList = [Car]()
...
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    Car car = carList[indexPath.row]
    cell.displayCarName!.text= car.Name
    cell.displayMpg!.text = String(car.Mpg)
    cell.displayCarPrice!.text = String(car.Price)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I knew there was a better way. I need to think more in object oriented ways. I really don't know why it is so hard to think in OOP way. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: As an aside, sometimes you just don't want a Class for whatever reason (usually memory overhead).  In that case, go with named tuples!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Quick question, as I previously stated I'm having a hard time thinking in an object oriented way, all of the programs I have created are more of a procedural programs with only a little bit of OOP. **Is it common to have classes as `simple` as the one suggested?** If yes, that is one of my problems since I don't create classes unless I need some big logic.  I have never created one as simple as the suggested example. Thanks

Comment: @fs_tigre Yes, it is very common, especially on the model side of your Model-View-Controller design (in this case, `Car` is definitely on the model side). Simple classes like that are used for grouping data for persistence, data transfer, display, and so on.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Got it, thanks a lot for the clarification. Now, for readability purposes, would this be a good case for the use of a `struct` instead of a class since the code is mainly for structuring purposes and no inheritance etc. is needed? I know the differences between classes and structs in Swift and I know both will work just fine but again I'm just thinking about code readability. Thanks a lot for your help. I know this is the basics of OOP and I should probably already know this but I don't :(,  so this helps me a lot.

Comment: @fs_tigre In this situation it probably does not matter much, because `Car` has only three fields, and it does not participate in inheritance hierarchies. If your model grows to include other kinds of vehicles, with different sets of properties, `class` would have an advantage. Having significantly more fields (around 20 or so) would make `struct`s too "heavy" on copying, so you'd have to start treating them with more care. But in the example above it wouldn't matter at all.

Comment: I see, I forgot about copy vs reference, thanks lot for your help.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that I just bought a small book called `The Fundamental Concepts of Object-Oriented Programming` and coincidentally the first thing the author talks about is *Parallels Arrays* and how they were used in procedural programming before OOP, than he goes onto showing how to use structs in stead.  I haven't read the whole book but so far it looks like it will be an interesting book. Thanks again *dasblinkenlight*.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to make a class for your data source

```
class SingleCellData {
  var displayCarName : String!
  var displayMpg : Int! 
  var displayCarPrice : Double! 
}
```

In table View

```
var cellData : [SingleCellData] = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let sData = cellData[indexPath.row]
    cell.displayCarName!.text= sData.displayCarName
    cell.displayMpg!.text = String(sData.displayMpg)
    cell.displayCarPrice!.text = String(StringsData.displayCarPrice)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can also move the text assignment logic to the `CustomCell` class itself:

```
// Car.swift

class Car {
    var name : String
    var mpg : Int
    var price : Double
}

// ViewController.swift

...
private var cars = [Car]()
...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.car = cars[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

// CustomCell.swift
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
   ...
   var car: Car? {
      didSet {
         displayCarName.text = car?.name
         displayMpg.text = car?.mpg
         displayPrice.text = car?.price
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.